# IE8 special char with Charset

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

I have a big problem with IE8

I have field TextArea, user write everything use lot of characters ç àèì áéí, show ok in textarea, debug in Javascript and Jquery ok too.
but when I send to MVC controller change characters special for "?"

I tryed in Chrome and FF IE 10 or 11 , its ok, problem is only IE 8

I trying post using $.post,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my controller",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", //I use too for test ISO-8859-1
        success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
                alert("Error!");
        }
});
```

I put too in master page and this page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

I tried create a Form too, but I try to send to form but happen same thing.

Comment: Have you tried adding the following line inside your controller action: `Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");`?

Comment: plus +1 for "I have a big problem with IE8." :)

Comment: I never had use this code, I put in first line of my method, but same thing.